# Google Play Store Policy on WebView and Admob

Tags: google-play, admob, android-webview, google-play-console

In my app, I am showing list of websites and on click of each item I will show the particular website with in my app (Detail page). I would like to know is there any problem to show a banner ad (AdMob) in the  Detail Page, like Intellectual property violation...etc

**In short I would like to avoid app rejection from my Google play store account**.

Attaching the XML of my Details Page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/tab_checked"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/cv_main"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </WebView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">


    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Developer questions about app store policy are off-topic https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: You can get more detail on policies here: https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the banner does not appear over the content but in a sperate place, Ad [overlapping with app content (against policy)](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en#zippy=)

You should show in very clear way that you are showing websites that you do not own in this area (Detail page) to avoid [Impersonation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888374) (unless you own these websites)

Also consider that the owners of these websites could report you to Google and ask for your app to be remove. as mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9899034#zippy=%2Cexamples-of-common-violations)

> We don’t allow apps whose primary purpose is to drive affiliate traffic to a website or provide a webview of a website without permission from the website owner or administrator.

Make sure that your app have other functionality more than opening webpages.

> Apps whose primary purpose is to provide a webview of a website without permission:

Also if your app designed for families you [cant do this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9893335?hl=en) even if you own the app

> App functionality: Your app must not merely provide a webview of a website or have a primary purpose of driving affiliate traffic to a website, regardless of ownership of the website.

My recommendation: is not use banner in this case, even though you could do it in a way that does not violate any guideline, your app could be rejected many times and receive violation warnings.